# How to extend text as wide as its container?

Tags: html, css, text-align, justify

I have a div with a few words of text in it, which I want to extend as far as the div itself.

In other words, the word-spacing should automatically stretch until the last word reaches the edge of the div.

By reading about `text-align: justify`, I assumed that's exactly what it was supposed to do. But either I'm mistaken, or I'm doing something wrong: http://jsfiddle.net/rLnrtu0x/1/

**To illustrate:**

Right now, this is the result:

```
|text text text text                       |
```

But I am trying to achieve something like this:

```
|text        text         text         text|
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is there another method of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`text-align: justify` only works on content in any lines of text *but the last one* – and since you only have one line of text here, you see no effect at all.

Some browsers also support [`text-align-last`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align-last) specifically for such purposes.

But you can get this to work using a little trick as well: By seeing to it that the text content of your element does *not* actually constitute the last line – by inserting a pseudo element that takes up full width, so that it is forced to be on a second line.

```
#justify:after {
    content:"";
    display:inline-block;
    width:100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rLnrtu0x/2/

Apart from the `width`, `display:inline-block` is the important part here – if the element was simply `inline`, the `width` would have no effect, and if it was `block`, it would break the whole thing because it would not behave as a fake piece of “text” content in the first place.

If your goal is not only to align simple text, but actual elements (f.e. for an evenly distributed number of list items), then you might also want to look into *flexbox*.

Comment: @DCdaz: Well, being a little bit more elaborate also takes a little more time sometimes.

Comment: You really should have improved upon an already working answer instead of swooping in.

Comment: @DCdaz: I did not “swoop in”, there was no answer yet when I started typing mine.

Comment: Sorry but I cant comment on whether that is the case or not.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to force justify an element, you need to add something semantic in the end.

Use pseudo element is the simplest way. See this snippet.

```css
.justify {
  text-align: justify;
}
.justify:after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  line-height: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="justify">
  Lorem ipsum Ullamco labore quis exercitation ut.  
</div>
```

Comment: That has to be the weirdest solution I've ever seen lol. It works though, thanks!